# pandoc: Unknown reader: gfm

Tags: markdown, pandoc, ubuntu-18.04, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to use `pandoc` (version 1.19.2.4) on Ubuntu 18.04 to render github flavoured markdown with:

`pandoc --from gfm --to html README.md`

This gives the error `pandoc: Unknown reader: gfm`.

I guess I need to verify/install `gfm`, but its not clear how to do this.

How do I fix this error? How do I use pandoc to generate github flavoured markdown?

Comment: I was also able to get some results with pandoc 1.19.2.4 using `-f markdown_github`.  However, as the pandoc documentation notes, that reader is deprecated.  For example, it uses the same line breaks as the input Markdown file!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an old version of pandoc, you'll need pandoc 2.0 or later. Either update Ubuntu to a [sufficiently new version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pandoc), or download a version from the [latest release page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest).

Answer (score 1):

You need **NEW PANDOC**.

I wrote a script, that will **get** and **install** new pandoc from official github repo.

**Step #1** - Download:

```sh
wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases -O /tmp/pandocPage.html
urlPart=`grep "\.deb" /tmp/pandocPage.html | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f2-7 | cut -d'"' -f1`
wget "https://github.com/$urlPart" -O mypandoc.deb
rm /tmp/pandocPage.html           # remove junk
```

**Step #2** - Install `.deb` file (via `dpkg -i` command):

```sh
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/mypandoc.deb
rm /tmp/mypandoc.deb              # remove junk
```

That's it.